# Is there a proper way to manage temporary files in Spring MVC context?

Tags: spring, temporary-files

I mean I'm deleting them when I'm done but I want to cover all the possibilities and rule out the chance of leaving garbage behind.
I read about File.createTempFile but it only deletes the temp file after the VM has been stopped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can specify the folder where your files are stored you can create a scheduled task that runs each hour and deletes the files older than one hour.

Take a look at the @Scheduled annotation.